# Paypal - PHP SDK vs simple form

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

Are there any advantages with PHP SDK over simple form like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="buisnesstest@bla.com">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="produktname">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.bla.com/?whopay=123"/>

<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.bla.com"/>

<input type="image" name="submit">
</form>
```

When it's only for a membership and not like multiple shopping items with many details and quantities and so on?